# Page types don't show up

Tags: kentico

I'm a new kentico's user and I'm building a web page. For my reviews page I have created a page type that should show the name, type, roast and image of my product. Fields has been created and I can see the database added in my SQL server management.

My problem is: 
when I add it on my reviews page, the database content doesn't appear. The reviews page is still blank .

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the "review page" using the "review page type"? If so, the fields are under the "FORM" tab for you to enter data. Then in the template, you need to use a Repeater web part with transformation to transform the data you entered under the FORM tab to HTML.